# Is there any way to use a joystick as a mouse?

Tags: usb, mouse, input-device, gamepad, joystick

In order to cut down on connected devices, is there any way to use a connected USB gamepad as a mouse?

Bonus points to anyone who can make it also act as the keyboard.

As a clarification, the optimal result that I'm looking for is something like the [Pandora Minimenu](http://pandorawiki.org/Minimenu), which provides a simplified interface for use.

Comment: Just a thought: Mouse on my linux machine is at /dev/input/mouse0 and gamepad at /dev/input/js0. I was wondering if I can create an alternate mouse1 and symbolic link /dev/input/js0 to it!

Comment: May I suggest that you also ask this question on unix.SE?

Comment: @LordLoh. My understanding is that cross-posting is discouraged, and I would prefer that my answers be viewed in the context of getting something working on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: You can always reframe your question here and post a different one on unix.SE I think it is more of a linux question than something specific to raspberry pi.

Comment: I thought X input system did use joysticks for pointer control out of the box. Maybe that's just analogue ones (I've probably tried a PS3 one). Have you tried? Digital pads make terrible pointers, though.

Comment: If you do manage to point, you might be able to use an on-screen keyboard program for a keyboard.

Comment: Or maybe you need a bigger connected device http://www.2dayblog.com/images/2008/august/ps3_keyboard_attach_1.jpg  :)

Answer (score 1):

To send keyboard commands from your joystick, check out [joy2key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Joy2key).
There is some [example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Joy2key) on the Arch linux wiki.